# taxonomy-$taxonomy.php não funciona

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-types, taxonomia

Boa tarde.
Estou criando um site com mais de um Custom Post Type. Por exemplo:
O Custom Post Type "A" tem a taxonomia "Tipos" (tipo1 e tipo2).
O Custom Post Type "B" tem a taxonomia "Anos" (2016, 2015...).

Criei um arquivo `taxonomy-tipos.php` para o Custom Post Type "A". Assim eu consigo listar todos as itens do tipo1 e do tipo2 separadamente. Esse deu certo.

Então criei um arquivo `taxonomy-anos.php` para listar os itens de determinado ano. Mas, dessa vez, não funcionou. Quando clico em um ano, o wp pega o template `index.php` e não o `taxonomy-anos.php`.

(simplifiquei os nomes para facilitar o entendimento).

O código de criação da taxonomia que usei está transcrito logo abaixo. Está no arquivo `functions.php`. O arquivo com o template para essa taxonomia seria o `taxonomy-productionyear.php`. Foi exatamente o que fiz para outro Custom Post Type, que tem outra taxonomia.

```
add_action('init', 'taxonomy_production_year');
function taxonomy_production_year(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Publications Years', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Publication Year', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search for Year' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Years' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Year' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Year:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Year' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Year' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Year' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Year' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Year' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        'label'             => __( 'Year' ),
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_tag_cloud' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array(
            'slug'          => 'production/year',
            'with_front'    => false,
        ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'productionyear', 'post_type_production', $args );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema.
Fui em Configurações -> Links Permanentes -> Salvas alterações.
Então atualizei a página e funcionou.